# Input text doesn't take fractional numbers in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

```
Input Text    //*[@id=${widget}-payment-input-input]    100,999
Click Button    id=${widget}-init-payment-button
Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=${widget}-payment-input-error-message
Element Should Contain    id=${widget}-payment-input-error-message    Vous devez saisir un montant.
```

In the Jenkins job instead of value "100,999", "100999" appears.
Could you advice solutions?

Comment: Perhaps the `,` is treated as a thousands separator instead of decimal? Try with `"100.999"` to see if that makes the difference.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you perform these steps manually and insert 100,999 into that field, does it automatically hide the "," in the input field?